# Is there a way to get resolver aliases to work in RubyMine+Webpacker+Vue

Tags: webpack, rubymine, webpacker

This is a pretty esoteric question.

I use RubyMine (v 2020.1), Rails 6 with Webpacker 4 (which in turn uses Webpack 4.41), and Vue.js.

With this configuration, I get this annoying problem with the editor:

[image: RubyMine red-lining]

`common` and `components` are resolver aliases I set in `config/webpacker/custom.js`.

I cannot figure out how to get RubyMine to properly understand this configuration, and thereby give me proper parsing of the Vue component's style block `@import`s.  Neither the 'plain' alias `common` nor `~common` work.  Interestingly, url resolver aliases *in the same `.vue` file `<style>` sections* *DO* work, e.g. `url('~img/common/tooltip-triangle.svg')`

Comment: Would it be possible to share the project sample? Because there might be different reasons of the issue.

Comment: @Olivia. This is a private project; I could try and create a standalone minimal reproduction, but it'll take some time.  Is there a list of the issues which might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in your project's settings - just specify the path to your `config/webpacker/custom.js` on Settings/Preferences | Languages and Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack.

I also assume that you have something similar to the following snippet in your `custom.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "common": "/path/to/common"
    }
  }
}
```